# passing value from combobox with ajax to another php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, combobox

change functions are for the selected item on combobox. Input is the textbox. When the lastly entered value to textbox variables are successfully sending the javascript variables but the alert returns nothing when its show.

```
<script>
$(function(){
$("#classroom").on("change", function() {
     $("#segment_course").show();
      });
$("#course").on("change", function() {
     $("#segment_time").show();
      });
$("#time").on("change", function() {
     $("#segment_duration").show();
      });
    var e= document.getElementById("classroom");
    var selectclass= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
   var f= document.getElementById("course");
    var selectcourse= f.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var g= document.getElementById("duration");
    var drtion= g.value;
$("#duration").on("input", function() {  
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'classroom_add.php',
      data: ({selectedclass:selectclass,selectedcourse:selectcourse,courseduration:drtion}),
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    }); 
  });
});
</script>
```

this is the classroom_add.php its not showing anything also

```
$classroom=$_GET['selectedclass'];
$course=$_GET['selectedcourse'];
$duration=$_GET['drtion'];
    echo $classroom;
    echo $course;
    echo $duration;
```

Comment: I dont get it, why use `document.getElementById` when you're using jQuery?

Comment: its for selecting choosen value from combobox.

Comment: there was a mistake its taking values with jquery now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending object formatted data but you need to send data as query string to ajax get call.

Change this line:

```
data: ({selectedclass:selectclass,selectedcourse:selectcourse,courseduration:drtion}),
```

to this:

```
data: "selectedclass=" + selectedclass + "&selectedcourse=" + selectedcourse + "&courseduration=" + drtion,
```

Also put exit() or die() at the end of your php script to close the script and return immediately. Hopefully it will work. Thanks.

Comment: i posted it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="twelve wide stretched column" >
    <div class="ui tab segment active" data-tab="a">
    <div class="ui form">
        <div class="field">
          <label>Please Select Classroom</label>
          <select class="ui search dropdown" id="classroom">
           <option value="">Select Classroom</option>
          ';
        $faculty_id = $_SESSION["faculty_id"];
        $class = "select * from class where faculty=$faculty_id";
        $result = $conn->query($class);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($fill = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $class_id = $fill['class_no'];
                $name = $fill['cls_name'];
                echo "<option value=$class_id>$name</option>";
            }
        }

 echo '
        </select>
        </div>
               ';
        echo'
        <div class="ui basic segment" style="display: none;" id="segment_course">
            <div class="field">
            <label>Please Select Course</label>
            <select class="ui search dropdown" id="course">
                 <option value="">Select Course</option>
          ';

        $faculty_id = $_SESSION["faculty_id"];
        $class = "select * from course where faculty=$faculty_id";
        $result = $conn->query($class);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($fill = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $course_id = $fill['code_section'];
                $course_name = $fill['name'];
                echo "<option value=$course_id>$course_id - $course_name</option>";
            }
        }
echo '
            </select>
            </div>
        </div>
          <div class="ui basic segment" style="display: none;" id="segment_time">
                <div class="field">
                 <label>Please Select Course Start Time</label>
                 <select class="ui search dropdown" id="time">
                 <option value="">Select Start Time</option>
                 <option value="1">9:00-10:00</option>
                 <option value="2">10:00-11:00</option>
                 <option value="3">11:00-12:00</option>
                 <option value="4">12:00-13:00</option>
                 <option value="5">13:00-14:00</option>
                 <option value="6">14:00-15:00</option>
                 <option value="7">15:00-16:00</option>
                 <option value="8">16:00-17:00</option>
                 <option value="9">17:00-18:00</option>
                 <option value="10">18:00-19:00</option>
                 <option value="11">19:00-20:00</option>
                 <option value="12">20:00-21:00</option>
                </select>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ui basic segment" style="display: none;" id="segment_duration">
              <div class="ui field">
                 <label>Please Enter Course Duration</label>
                <div class="ui fluid input">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Duration of Course" id="duration">
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the html part for the related divs.

Comment: Thanks for posting the html. I will be back shortly.

Comment: This line in the js script: $("#duration").on("input", function() { 
What did you mean by input? Input is a tag not an event. You can use keyup or blur to track the changes in the input field. But I see you have some classes ui fluid input etc. If you are using any js library to beautify the input make sure you can get the original input field value.

Comment: input is working i wrote values to console without problem inside the input function when the value inputed inside duration textbox.but its not sending to other page. I am using semantic UI library.

Comment: i think i solved it for this point. Its not showing in sended page but its returns back to first page with inside valules from first page. thank you.

Comment: Glad you sorted out the issue. Cheers! :)